# How to query nested json object in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I create a collection with 8 documents, i want to query my `releasedTime`
, here is my structure:

[image]

I try this query first , i can get the object movie data

```
db.collection.find({}, {movie: 1})
```

I don't know what to do next.
I try this query:

```
db.collection.find({}, {movie.film: 1})
```

I suppose i will get `film` object data but its not working.

If i want to get all of my documents `releasedTime` data, what is the correct query ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add a sample document and the expected output

Comment: I get an answer now. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to wrap your projection key within quotes

```
db.collection.find({}, {"movie.film": 1})
```

Here is my try on mongo console with sample data:

{ item: "journal", status: "A", size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" }, instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 } ] }
[Check out this screen shot for the corresponding commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Kdg.png)

In your case the query would be :

```
db.collection.find({}, {"movie.film.releasedDate": 1})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i add the quotes and its working.